# Rails 4 - Associations & Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations

I'm trying to make an app in rails 4.

I have models called `Organisation`, `Profile` and `Project`.

The associations are:

`Organisation  has_many :profiles`

`Profile belongs_to :organisation`

`Profile has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy`

`Projects  belongs_to :profile`

**In my organisation show page, I want to show the projects that belong to profiles where those profiles belong to organisations.**

How can I achieve that?

This is the basic structure, which I am trying to adapt to link organisation to project through profile.

```
<% Organisation.find(params[:id]).projects.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                    <% group.compact.each do |project| %>
```

I don't understand how to use scopes, but I tried making one in my project model, as:

```
scope :by_organisation, ->(profile.organisation_id) { where(profile_id: profile.organisation_id) }
```

I'm not sure if I am on the right track. I tried making another one in my organisation model as:

```
scope :relevant_projects, ->(organisation_id) { where(organisation_id: project.profile.organisation_id) }


<% Organisation.relevant_projects.find(params[:id]).projects.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
                                <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                    <% group.compact.each do |project| %>
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

I don't know what this means. What part of the scope is an argument?

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

I tried adding associations as:

Organisation:

```
has_many :projects, through: :profiles
```

Project:

```
belongs_to :organisation, through: :profile
```

Then I update the show page in the organisation folder to:

```
   <% Organisation.projects.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3).each do |group| %>
                                    <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
                                        <% group.compact.each do |project| %>
```

However, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `projects' for #<Class:0x007fe1e31988f0>
```

Comment: Your `relevant_projects` scope expects a parameter which should be your `organization_id`.

Comment: After going through your question, I think you should consider `has_many :through` association here. Like you can add in `Organisation` model like `has_many :projects, through: :profiles` . You can do something like this then `@organisation.projects`

Comment: I tried the has many through - but I get the error undefined method 'projects'. I copied my attempt above. Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `belongs_to :organisation, through: :profile` You don't need to add this to `Project` model.  And, get an object of `Organisation` and then use association on it. Like `@organisation = Organisation.first` and then `@organisation.projects` should return you the related projects.

Comment: Did this approach solved your problem ?

Comment: I put: <% Organisation.find(params[:id]).projects.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3).each do |group| %>
                            I just can't check if it works yet because I've run into another problem. I'lll come back when I solve that to see if this works. I don't actually know what find(params) means so I'm not sure if im on the right track. Thanks very much for the help though. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` is occurring because of following scope which expects `organisation_id` as a parameter.

```
scope :relevant_projects, ->(organisation_id) { where(organisation_id: project.profile.organisation_id) }
```

---

**Alternative**

You can use `has_many through:` association here which can be done just by adding the following line of code to your `Organisation` model -

```
has_many :projects, through: :profiles
```

Now, you can simply do the following to get related `projects` of an organisation -

```
Organization.first.projects
```

Or, you can find an organization first from your database table and then get its projects like followings -

```
@organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id]) #params[:id] provides an id of organisation and it is being fetched from the database using this query
@organisation.projects #returns all the related projects of this organisation
```

Hope it helps!